# How to bind an error handler in case ajax call fails?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.get(viewUrl + para, function (data) {
    dialogDiv.html(data);
    ...
});
```

Is there some way that I can add an error check to this? Something that will call a function if the get fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `$.get()` is shorthand for the `$.ajax()` method, you could just use that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: viewUrl + para,
  success: function (data) {
    dialogDiv.html(data);
   ...
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("Error!");
  }
});
```

I recommend this option as it (for me at least) seems far better suited for more complex AJAX requests. Sure adding an error callback may not constitute it being complex, but it's good to know your options.

Comment: I wonder why this answer was upvoted. `url: $.get(viewUrl + para,` ? What's that? Edited that for you, but tell me, why would you use .ajax() if you could use .get() ?

Comment: D'oh! Copy and paste error... will edit to further explain my reasoning.

Comment: Hello, viewURL + para are two strings that I use. One representing the URL and the other the parameters. Ben just copied from my question which I think is okay.

Comment: @Jessica: no, it wasn't initially okay.

Comment: @Martin is right, I had incorrectly copied and pasted originally. Thanks for editing Martin, that's exactly what it should have been.

Comment: @BenEverard: I like when answerer accepts his downvote without being mad. Undownvoted :)

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can, use [`.error()`](http://api.jquery.com/error/) method

```
$.get(viewUrl + para, function (data) {
    dialogDiv.html(data);
    // ...
}).error(function(e) {
   alert("an error occured");
   console.log(e);
});
```

There are even more events for handling ajax events

```
.success()
.error()
.complete()
```

However, they're being deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Instead of these, you should use (if using jQuery >= 1.5)

```
.done()
.fail()
.always();
```

Comment: As jQuery documentation [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) sais, you can use .error() .success() and .complete() to specify callbacks for those case.

Comment: @EngineerGio: I'm in proccess of adding these

Comment: +1 for the deprecated stuff, didn't even realise these new callbacks existed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jqxhr = $.get("example.php", function() {
    alert("success");
  })
  .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
  .error(function() { alert("error"); })
  .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: please, at least describe your answer a bit more, it's pretty poor now. (you just copied it from the documentation)